# How to set DefaultIterationPath in the Team Settings of Azure Devops via REST API?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I want to set the "DefaultIterationPath" in Azure Devops Services for a Team via REST API (or API DLLs from MS wrapping the REST API).
This could be done with the method UpdateTeamSettings.

*Reading* the team settings could be done with this (that is ok):

```
TeamContext teamContext = new TeamContext(prjinfo.Name, sTeamName);
TeamSetting teamSetting = work_client.GetTeamSettingsAsync(teamContext).Result;
```

Writing the team settings with the method *UpdateTeamSettings* needs to provide a TeamSettingsPatch.

```
TeamSettingsPatch patch = new TeamSettingsPatch();
// patch.DefaultIteration = <Guid of the new DefaultIterationPath>
work_client.UpdateTeamSettingsAsync(patch, teamContext);
```

TeamSettingsPatch has a property:

```
public Guid? DefaultIteration { get; set; }
```

but not a property like the following (or similar):

```
public string DefaultIterationPath { get; set; }
```

Where can I provide the new DefaultIterationPath? Is there a way to create it, get its Guid and set the Guid in TeamSettingsPatch object?

Same problem with the REST API.

Are there any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nomenclature for this is a bit weird and can be hard to discover. Areas and iterations are both internally known as "classification nodes". Once you know that, finding and creating them is easy.

You're looking for the `WorkItemTrackingHttpClient` service. That contains a method [`GetClassificationNodeAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.webapi.workitemtrackinghttpclientbase.getclassificationnodeasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet) that allows you to search for areas and iterations. That will contain the GUID of the entity.

Comment: Thank you. I got it now. Saved my day. For a wrap up see my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Short wrap up what I did:

```
workitem_tracking_client = team_project_collection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
...
WorkItemClassificationNode newNode = new WorkItemClassificationNode();
newNode.Name = sIterationName;
newNode.StructureType = TreeNodeStructureType.Iteration;
WorkItemClassificationNode result = workitem_tracking_client.CreateOrUpdateClassificationNodeAsync(newNode, prjinfo.Name, TreeStructureGroup.Iterations).Result;
...
TeamSettingsPatch patch = new TeamSettingsPatch();
patch.DefaultIteration = result.Identifier;
var newsett = work_client.UpdateTeamSettingsAsync(patch, teamContext).Result;
```

This will set the DefaultBacklogIteration.